# A list containing zero elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list containing zero and nonzero elements. How can I throw away zero elements and just keep non zero ones.

Comment: `Cases[{0, f, y, e, 1, 2, 3}, Except[0]]`

Comment: DeleteCases[list,0]

Comment: Instead of either of the two suggestions above, I recommend `Select[list, # != 0 &]` for the reason that pattern matching differentiates between `0.` and `0` while `==` has a small tolerance even for machine precision zeros.  Pattern matching can be fixed by using `0|0.` in place of `0`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
Select[list, # != 0 &]
```

for the simplest solution.

---

A non-obvious solution that can be quite fast (for versions $\ge 8$), especially for packed arrays, is

```
Pick[list, Unitize[list], 1]
```

This'll give you better performance than `Select`.

---

A warning about pattern matching: it differentiates between exact `0` and inexact `0.`, thus

```
In[2]:= DeleteCases[{0., 0, 1}, 0]
Out[2]= {0., 1}

In[3]:= DeleteCases[{0., 0, 1}, 0.]
Out[3]= {0, 1}
```

You can use the pattern `0|0.` but using comparison (`==` or `!=`) is both clearer and `==` allows for greater differences from zero (that might arise due to numerical roundoff errors during calculations) than `===` and pattern matching.  So I recommend `==`.  (You might google for `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` and `` Internal`$SameQTolerance `` if you wish to learn about these tolerances.)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {0, 0.0, 0 + 0 I, f, y, e, 1, 2, 3};
```

Using `PossibleZeroQ`

```
Select[Not @* PossibleZeroQ] @ list
```

{f, y, e, 1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 2):

Grabbing the list from @eldo and using `Extract`, `Position` and `PossibleZeroQ`:

```
list = {0, 0.0, 0 + 0 I, f, y, e, 1, 2, 3};

Extract[#, Position[#, x_ /; ! PossibleZeroQ[x], Heads -> False]] &@list

(*{f, y, e, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Grabbing the list from @eldo

```
list = {0, 0.0, 0 + 0 I, f, y, e, 1, 2, 3};
list /. x_ /; x == 0 -> Nothing
```

> `{f, y, e, 1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 2):

And another one is:

```
foo[list_] := 
  Module[{nonzeropositions, nonzeroelements}, 
   nonzeropositions = Flatten[SparseArray[list]["NonzeroPositions"]];
   nonzeroelements = list[[nonzeropositions]];
   Print["The non-zero elements of the list are:"];
   Return[nonzeroelements];];
```

which we test with ---again the list is from @eldo

```
test = {0, 0.0, 0 + 0 I, f, y, e, 1, 2, 3};
```

Now, we run

```
foo[test]
```

and we get

> [image: foo]