# Select non-zero elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a function that generates a list of numbers and variables .
e.g.
`F[w]= {wx, wy, 5, 0}`

I want to select all non-zero elements i.e. `{wx,wy,5}`.

Comment: `Cases[{wx, wy, 5, 0, 0.}, Except[0 | 0.]]`.

Comment: Possible duplicates where one should be marked duplicate probably: [(42971)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42971/a-list-containing-zero-elements) and [(47214)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47214/how-to-find-non-zero-elements-of-a-list-containing-zeros-and-symbols).

Comment: Also look at the proposed duplicates. There are other solutions that might be better, based on comments by the posters there. (Also, `DeleteCases[{wx, wy, 5, 0, 0.}, 0|0.]` is probably more natural that my original.)

Comment: You can also do `{wx, wy, 5, 0, 0.} /. {0 | 0. -> Sequence[]}`.

Comment: Another possibility which might be more general is `list /. _?PossibleZeroQ -> Nothing` or `Select[ list , Not @* PossibleZeroQ ]`

Comment: There is also [pick](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113646/106). For example, `Pick[#, Chop[#], Except[0, _?AtomQ]] &@{wx, wy, 5, 0, 0.}` or (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113650/106), [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) in 'comments'):  `Pick[#, Chop[#], Except[0 | _List]] &@{wx, wy, 5, 0, 0.}]`

Answer (score 12):

For the "heck" of it and to wrap it all up:

Let's create a sufficiently large list and test for performance.

```
SeedRandom["115522"]; (* make this replicable *)

list = RandomVariate[ EmpiricalDistribution @ Range[10], 1*^6 ];

expressions = {
    "list /. _?PossibleZeroQ\[Rule]Nothing",
    "Select[ list, Not@*PossibleZeroQ ]",
    "DeleteCases[list,0|0.]",
    "Cases[list,Except[0|0.]]",
    "list /. 0|0. \[Rule] Nothing ",
    "Select[ list, #!=0& ]",
    "SparseArray[list][\"NonzeroValues\"]"
};

tfunc = Function[ expr,
    expr // RightComposition[
        ToExpression,
        Timing,
        First
    ]
];

runtimes = Map[ tfunc, expressions ];

BarChart[ { runtimes },
    ChartLegends -> { Style[#, FontFamily -> "Consolas"] & /@ expressions },
    LabelingFunction -> (Placed[PaddedForm[#, {3, 2}], Above] &),    
    PlotTheme -> "Business" 
]
```

> [image]

Comment: So the generality of [`PossibleZeroQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) (non-surprisingly) does come at a price.

Comment: Curious what the `SparseArray` solution times at on your test...

Comment: I really like your chart and  how you get your labels automatically (+1)

Comment: @ciao Added it ... impressively fast.

Answer (score 8):

```
SparseArray[list]["NonzeroValues"]
```

Should perform quite well on large lists...

Comment: +1. Indeed a very nice solution - not really obvious though. :)